# Windows Putty connect to OSX SSH Server with SSH key

Tags: windows, ssh

Could someone guide me to setting up OSX (10.10 Yosemite) so that I can ssh from Windows using putty to Mac, but using ssh key rather than password.

On the Mac I've enabled remote-login under sharing preferences, but unsure how to setup the private/public keys.

All articles that I find on the web guide how to connect to Linux from Mac, but I want the other way round and where the client is Windows.

PS - I'm a complete noob when it comes to Mac and have only been using it for 2 days now!

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use a program called *[PuttyGen.exe](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/download.html)* on the Windows side to generate a public and private key.

Using the "Generate" button, generate the keys using the above program.  You will then need to move the public key that is generated to your mac.  Save a copy of the private key to use later using the "Save private key" button.

On your windows machine copy the contents of your public key exactly and paste them in the **authorized_keys** file you will create below.  The easiest way I think is to open an ssh connection using *Putty* to your mac machine, the first time you will have to enter a username and password.  Then create the folders and file structure and use an editor to move the contents.  From the putty terminal window connected to your mac enter:

```
sudo mkdir ~/.ssh
sudo touch ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Then the editing part of the file you created:

```
vim ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Press the <kbd>i</kbd> key to insert text.  Paste in your public key, and press the keys <kbd>esc</kbd> then, <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> to save it.

Now you can re-open Putty and create a new session.  On the left hand tab expand **SSH** and select the **Auth tab**.  Towards the bottom you will need to browse and load in the Private key that you saved earlier.

[image: Putty Auth]

I got most of this from the help file in *PuttyGen.exe* the first time I did it.  When you open *Puttygen.exe* there is a **Help** tab up top.

[PuttyGen.exe download](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/download.html)

Comment: This is really helpful - I was sort of figuring these steps out - but unfortunately it isn't working - im getting a message `server refused our key` - any thoughts?

Comment: Does the key type matter? I've used SSH-2-RSA...

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to ssh to a user on the mac other than the one that has the authorized_keys file

Comment: `05817:~ chrismoutray$ sudo more ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` returns the contents of the public key file - and I'm using the username `chrismoutray` - I've copied and pasted to make sure no typos

Comment: Are you using the hostname to connect through putty, if so try using the IP instead

Comment: I'm using the IP - do I need to restart the ssh service (not sure how)?

Comment: No. you shouldn't It should work.  Can you confirm that your user name is "chrismoutray".  On the mac temrinal do a 'whoami' command

Comment: it returns `chrismoutray`, I'm 100% it's the right user since after the key refused message i can continue to login with the password - btw thanks for you patience

Comment: For what its worth I've tried regenerating the keys as `ssh-2 rsa` and `ssh-2 dsa` and also using 1024 bit instead of 2048. - also I tried pasting direct from the contents of the public file (has multiple lines) as well as from the puttygen ui (one line)

Comment: Do **not** use `sudo chown`. It will make the key fail to be read by ssh, rejecting any keys in authorized_keys. The rest of the steps should be followed.